# Not able to stop the service on UWP appx launch

Tags: service, uwp

I have created appx using makeappx tool. After installing appx,on launch I have added below code to stop the service:

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("MyService");
    string servicestatus = sc.Status.ToString();
    if (servicestatus == "Running")
    {
     sc.Stop();
    }
```

On launch I found the service was not stop and getting an exception.But when I run the same appx from start menu with run as administrator I found service was getting stop. I think the issue was related with admin previlages as I know appx always launch with fulltrustprocess and not with adminprevilages. 
It will be great help if we can stop the service on appx launch itself.

Answer (score 1):

This is to be expected; if you launch CMD as a normal user and try to stop a service, you will get Access Denied:

```
C:\Users\Peter>net stop "Bonjour Service"
System error 5 has occurred.

Access is denied.
```

When running elevated, it works:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>net stop "Bonjour Service"
The Xamarin Bonjour Service service is stopping.
The Xamarin Bonjour Service service was stopped successfully.
```

Apps converted via the Desktop Bridge cannot auto-elevate; the user has to do that.

Comment: Thanks For Input, Peter. But can we have way by which we can auto elevate the app? or any solution because on launch I want to uninstall the desktop version of same app which uses service also. I am able to uninstall it only when service is stopped and not able to do when service is running.

Comment: No, sorry. One of the main value propositions of UWP is that apps can't mess with the system. You will have to ask your users to elevate if you want to change the system.